# Python - convert json format column to dataframe

Tags: python, json

I have a dataframe with single column and it's in json format.

```
result
[{'Start Time':'2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'Arrival Time':'2021-02-02 00:00:00'...
```

and I want to convert this json string to dataframe.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

d = json.loads(df['result'].replace("'",'"'))
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

I get **Typeerror: the json obejct must be str, bytes or bytearray, not series.**
```

Am I missing a step?
Now I would like to build a new dataframe which shows the json column as a single dataframe, how can this be done?
I've been struggle with this for whole day.
Below format is output I am looking for.

```
start Time                Arrival Time
2021-01-01 00:00:00       2021-02-02 00:00:00
2021-01-02 00:00:00       2021-02-03 00:00:00
2021-01-03 00:00:00       2021-02-04 00:00:00
2021-01-04 00:00:00       2021-02-05 00:00:00
2021-01-05 00:00:00       2021-02-06 00:00:00
```

Comment: If  you already have a dataframe, why do you want to load it again from JSON ?

Comment: You already have a dataframe, as it indicates the error.

Comment: because it's in json format so I can see all the data values easily

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load the column values of an existing dataframe as a different data frame. A simple approach is below

```
df["result"] = df["result"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("'", '"'))
df["result"] = df["result"].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x))
new_df = DataFrame(df["result"].values.tolist())
```

This will give you a dataframe with `Start Time`, `Arrival Time` .. as columns.

But, since your structure already seems to be stringified dict, you can do this as well.

```
import ast
import pandas as pd
raw_data = "[{'Start Time': '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'Arrival Time': '2021-02-02 00:00:00', 'temp': 35.6},{'Start Time': '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 'Arrival Time': '2021-02-03 00:00:00', 'temp': 40.1},{'Start Time': '2021-01-03 00:00:00', 'Arrival Time': '2021-02-04 00:00:00', 'temp': 25.6}]"
json_data = ast.literal_eval(raw_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)
```

Comment: Thanks but I get AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'. How can I fix thiss error?

Comment: Well I expected your dataframe with a single column with many rows of `{'Start Time':'2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'Arrival Time':'2021-02-02 00:00:00'}`, If not post your original structure, if it came from a CSV

Comment: I've actually extract the data from database and the structure is repeat of same variables. [{'Start Time':'2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'Arrival Time':'2021-02-02 00:00:00', 'temp':35.6},{'Start Time':'2021-01-02 00:00:00', 'Arrival Time':'2021-02-03 00:00:00', 'temp':40.1},{'Start Time':'2021-01-03 00:00:00', 'Arrival Time':'2021-02-04 00:00:00', 'temp':25.6} ]" and these are all in one column so I want this as normal dataframe so I can see them easily.

Comment: You can use `ast` module to directly load it as a dict. Updated answer